# Making a Twitter Bot in PHP?

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I've made a twitter bot using the CURL library for PHP, and a MySQL db.

But I would like to expand its functionality by automatically retweeting tweets marked with a certain hashtag.

I do not know quite how to do this, so would any of you be willing to point me to a learning resource on how to do this?

Or if you really want to, show me how to add this functionality?

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [daemon](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/). You have to make it search every time for the hashtag you are looking for (check [search documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search)).

Then you'll have to [retweet](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-retweet).

And perhaps, you shall save each retweet in a Data Base, so your daemon won't duplicate tweets.